# Does NAudio support converting MP3 to WAV in a .Net Core api running in Linux?

Tags: asp.net-core, mp3, wav, naudio

I am trying to find a way to convert a mp3 file to wav in a .net core 3.1 api running in Linux. Can I make use of the NAudio library to do that? I know they support Windows, but not sure about Linux

Answer (score 2):

Looks like NAudio support only Windows, related open issue https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/184

UPD 2020-06-26. Thank for comment from Tim Davis, you can use NLayer (https://github.com/naudio/NLayer)+NAudio to convert mp3.

Comment: This is entirely untrue especially in 2020. I am running NAudio on Linux with NLayer on Linux and Docker with .Net Core

Comment: Original question was about NAudio, not NLayer. However, my answer may be confusing indeed.